# Prisma transaction in nodejs and typescript not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma

I have 100 over record to update. So I use transaction but I got following error -:

Argument of type '(tx: any) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PrismaPromise[]'.
Type '(tx: any) => Promise' is missing the following properties from type 'PrismaPromise[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 28 more.

May I know how to solve?

```
await prisma.$transaction(async (tx :any) /*error here*/ => {

    const updateSong = await tx.songs.update({
      where: {
        id: d.id,
      },
      data: {
        duration: duration,
      },
    })

  })
```

Comment: Did you enable interactive transactions feature?

Comment: Yes. Here it is.
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["interactiveTransactions"]
}

Answer (score 15):

I got the same error, I fix that with added `previewFeatures = ["interactiveTransactions"]`
and then regenerate my schema with `npx prisma generate`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I fixed the issue after take out async keyword from for loop.

Comment: Nasrul I'd add in the answer which file you need to add that to, the whole block, it wasn't hard to find though.  @AlexAung why not mark this as the answer so the question shows up as answered?

Answer (score 9):

The `previewFeatures = ["interactiveTransactions"]` in your `schema.prisma` file. Should look like this:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["interactiveTransactions"]
}
```